# Scoping not respected with service locator in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, inversion-of-control, service-locator

Parts of my code need to use a ServiceLocator because constructor injection isn't supported.

My startup class configures the services. I have some that are transient, others which are singleton and others scoped.

For example:

```
services.AddScoped<IAppSession, AppSession>();
services.AddScoped<IAuthentication, Authentication>();
services.AddScoped<NotificationActionFilter>();
```

At the end of my service definitions, I have the following block of code, which sets up the service locator.

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
DependencyResolver.Current = new DependencyResolver();
DependencyResolver.Current.ResolverFunc = (type) =>
{
    return serviceProvider.GetService(type);
};
```

I noticed that in a given request, I am not receiving the same instance from the service locator that I am from the constructor injection. Instances returned from the service locator appear to be singletons and do not respect the scoping.

The code for `DependencyResolver` is as follows:

```
public class DependencyResolver
{
    public static DependencyResolver Current { get; set; }

    public Func<Type, object> ResolverFunc { get; set; }

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        return (T)ResolverFunc(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You don't re-create scope, that's why scoped services do not respect the scoping. Also you have 2 ServiceProviders - it  explains why you're receiving different instances

Comment: Could you provide an implementation for DependencyResolver?

Comment: @AlexRiabov I'll add the full implementation in now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest creating a middleware which will set ServiceProvider to the one which is used in other places:

```
public class DependencyResolverMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public DependencyResolverMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        DependencyResolver.Current.ResolverFunc = (type) =>
        {
            return httpContext.RequestServices.GetService(type);
        };

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Also, `DependencyResolver` should be updated to support such behavior:

```
public class DependencyResolver
{
    private static readonly AsyncLocal<Func<Type, object>> _resolverFunc = new AsyncLocal<Func<Type, object>>();

    public static DependencyResolver Current { get; set; }

    public Func<Type, object> ResolverFunc
    {
        get => _resolverFunc.Value;
        set => _resolverFunc.Value = value;
    }

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        return (T)ResolverFunc(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Don't forget to register it in `Configure` method in Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseMiddleware<DependencyResolverMiddleware>();
}
```

Comment: This won't work. There is a race condition on setting the resolver function with simultaneous requests.

Comment: @Sam, you're right, I've updated the answer, so this shouldn't be a problem any more

Comment: Great work, thanks. Also - hadn't heard of AsyncLocal, good to learn something new.